# error in installing ABB ROS server

Tags: ros, abb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ABB ros server on my Yumi IRB14000 controller, I go through the ros tutorial for installing the server step by step. The problem appears that T_ROB1 is not installed and the error in flex pendant is that " Task ROB_1 will not be installed or it will not be possible to execute RAPID motion instructions".

Any suggestion to solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274706/error-in-installing-abb-ros-server/) by [Ahmad](https://answers.ros.org/users/32189/ahmad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `abb_driver` package was not written with YuMi in mind, meaning that it targets single group robots only. Both the motion and joint state servers have no concept of multiple motion groups.

That said it is possible to run *two* instances of the two tasks, edited slightly to use different port nrs, and assigned to the two separate groups (on the controller). This has been done by many groups already, and the official ABB driver is set to receive an upgrade to support this (multiple motion groups) as well as add EGM support soon.

One example of a fork that you could use already would be the fork of Örebro University: [OrebroUniversity/yumi](https://github.com/OrebroUniversity/yumi).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0